# How does Jackson use Earth's point of origin when dialling off Klorel's ship?

Tags: stargate, stargate-sg1

In Stargate SG-1 episode 2.01 The Serpent's Lair, Daniel dials off the ship to the Alpha Site, and later explains that he was close enough to Earth to use Earth as the point of origin. But how does he do that exactly? It's not like the DHD on the ship would have an Earth point of origin symbol (sun over a pyramid).

Comment: Note that the sun-over-pyramid is only consistently the point of origin symbol on the Egyptian stargate. The Antarctic stargate (which is technically the original Earth stargaze) often has [this](http://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/Beta_Gate?file=0eb.svg) point of origin symbol instead.

Comment: (and it's generally considered a production error when it has the sun-over-pyramid)

Answer (score 7):

It is established in several episodes, notably "Sacrifices," that there is one unique symbol on every gate, with that symbol being the point of origin. Of course, *SG-1* was stunningly inconsistent with this over the course of the series, so this is contradicted in other episodes. Still, it's te closest to a good answer the series ever provided.

Comment: So if the gate is moved, the point of origin symbol stays the same obviously. Does that simply mean any gate can dial from anywhere in the galaxy using its unique point of origin symbol? What does Daniel mean when he says that he used Earth's point of origin?

Comment: @MarkPage: "Sacrifices" would seem to imply that the answer is yes, you can use the point of origin symbol from anywhere. It's possible that what Daniel meant was that he dialled an address from Earth, since gate addresses differ due to different coordinates if you are on a different planet.

Comment: @MarkPage - 'Point of Origin' is kinda a misnomer when the symbol is just a unique identifier of the Gate/DHD. Remember the Antartic Gate? That DHD/gate had a different symbol I'm pretty sure.

Comment: @Robotnik: Yes it did.

Comment: Dialling with a DHD has the added advantage that you only dial in your destination and hit the big red button - but as @JamesSheridan said in his answer, that was inconsistently used as well.

Comment: Those inconsistencies always bug the crap out of me. I hate it when "production teams" miss those details... then they get mixed into canon and "we" have to try and figure out how the hell that would even be possible!! I just finished watching Stargate Atlantis episode where the team returns from the planet Michael was creating his giant bug army. In the control room we hear the gate turning, they say "we have an IDC," they remove the shield, then the gate activates... now comes the difficult task of someone explaining how this is possible...

Answer (score 0):

Each dhd has 1 unique symbol and daniel being the person who dials the off world gates most often would see it   so when he dials the alpha site to get off the ship he sees the symbol and instinctively hits that button as it is unique to that dhd